# Code optimality

Tags: java, performance, list, swap, indexof

Every time I'm coding I have dilemma between creating more variables and using methods, that make code more clear but less optimal? Can you tell me what is better for our application performance?

For example:

```
protected static <T> void exch(List<T> list, Object o1, Object o2) {
    list.set(list.indexOf(o1), list.set(list.indexOf(o2), list.get(list.indexOf(o1))));
}
```

Should I use:

```
indexOf(o1)
```

twice or make temp variable instead?

PS Just to make it clear for you. I'm writing few types of sorting methods for my university project. We're sorting lists that have ~150k elements. I would really like to get the best performance.

Comment: You should not exchange on *objects* to begin with if you sort, but on *indices*.

Comment: Had you considered that using a temporary variable might make the code more clear? Since there would be less information on 1 line.

Comment: Well, maybe you're right. But what about memory? Is it really worth to create new variable every time I'm comparing them? I heard garbage collector is so slow :/

Comment: @classOlek: Measure the performance for yourself to see how each performs (making a local variable vs. not).  I don't think introducing a local int variable will impact garbage collection, as that's for objects.

Comment: Objects that don't leave the method can usually be virtualised by the JIT compiler, so they don't get GC'd. But in this case, the type would be `int`, which is not managed by the garbage collector.

Comment: So making temp variable in such methods do not really affect our memory at all? So in this case, it would be better to make temp instead of this two indexOf calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you exchange **on objects**, the best you can do is indeed first calculate the `indexOf(o1)` once, since this is **an *O(n)* operation**: meaning that if you have a list with ~100k elements, it will require approximately twice the time compared to ~50k elements in the *worst* case. You do not want to do this expensive task twice. So you can optimize it to:

```
protected static <T> void exch(List<T> list, T o1, T o2) {
    int i1 = list.indexOf(o1);
    list.set(i1, list.set(list.indexOf(o2), list.get(i1)));
}
```

That's however not all. You do **not need to call `list.get(i1)`**: you know the result will be `o1` (given you did not override the `.equals(..)` method. But if you are sorting, I assume that you have a reference to the *real* object, not to an *equivalent* object. So you can rewrite it to:

```
protected static <T> void exch(List<T> list, T o1, T o2) {
    int i2 = list.indexOf(o2);
    list.set(list.indexOf(o1),o2);
    list.set(i2,o1);
}
```

It is of vital importance here to **first obtain the index of `o2`**: since once you have `list.set(..,o2)`, there are **two indices that map to `o2`**. In order to get the old one, we first have obtain the index.

Declaring an `int` in a method has **no impact on the garbage collection process**: the `int` will be declared on the *call stack* or it will use an accumulator (and thus have no memory address at all). That depends on your processor architecture, etc. Nevertheless the impact of declaring an `int` is minimal in terms of speed. Making a method call alone will have more impact: you make a call frame on the call stack, have to jump to that method, etc. The overhead is "large" compared to declaring one `int`.

Nevertheless I think your sorting algorithm is of **bad design** if you exchange objects by ***fetching* there index**. As said before this is an *O(n)* operation. If you do **bookkeeping on the indices**. You can make it an *O(1)* operation (this will result in a speedup of approximately ~50k) so that is where the real speedup lies (even if you manage to get the most out of the `indexOf` method, it inherently will be outperformed by a method working on indices). You can then implement it like:

```
protected static <T> void exch(List<T> list, int i1, int i2) {
    T o1 = list.get(i1);
    list.set(i1,list.get(i2));
    list.set(i2,o1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I was writing the details of that method I'd probably do this if I was going for readability.

```
protected static <T> void exch(List<T> list, Object o1, Object o2) {
    int indexOfO1 = list.indexOf(o1);
    int indexOfO2 = list.indexOf(o2);
    // TODO: Handle if either indexOf was out of range.
    list.set(indexOfO2, o1);
    list.set(indexOfO1, o2);
}
```

I don't think doing it in one line like you have will matter in terms of performance.  Read about premature optimization.